# tf converter all mapped while still encounter unresolved custom op

Tags: python, tensorflow

In order to deploy dummy model from tf to edgetpu board, I already made a model has all operations passed and mapped to edgetpu. However, when I use tflite interpreter to run inference, it shows that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_model.py", line 6, in <module>
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
...
RuntimeError: Encountered unresolved custom op: edgetpu-custom-op.Node number 0 (edgetpu-custom-op) failed to prepare.
```

And this is my simple addition model showing by edgetpu_compilter -s option:

```
Operator                       Count      Status

ADD                            1          Mapped to Edge TPU
QUANTIZE                       2          Mapped to Edge TPU
```

I checked, the tf.add should be able to execute no matter whether on cpu or edge tpu.

But one weird thing is that while I use visualize.py to inspect, it shows the following:

```
Tensors
index   name    type    shape   buffer  quantization
0   input   UINT8   [2, 3]  0   {'quantized_dimension': 0, 'scale': [0.003921], 'details_type': 'NONE', 'zero_point': [0]}
1   out UINT8   [2, 3]  0   {'quantized_dimension': 0, 'scale': [0.027404], 'details_type': 'NONE', 'zero_point': [0]}
Ops
index   inputs  outputs builtin_options opcode_index
0   
[0] 
[1] None    CUSTOM (0)
```

So, maybe my question would be: why addition operation is still called CUSTOM op here? And is this the reason why allocated_tensors fails to recognize it?

Comment: I main goal is try to deploy whatever model to edgetpu. The point is, it must be a customized model, not mobilenet or something popular. And now it is also OK to use whatever operation(s) that can be mapped to edgetpu.

Comment: Did you try inference on an EdgeTPU device? Also, can you provide more details on how you are generating the model & doing inference? The edgetpu compilation process, as far as I know, converts the model to a format thats only 'acceptable' by the EdgeTPU (and not a CPU). If you want to run the same model on a CPU, you shouldn't compile it for EdgeTPU.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Then re-read the instructions at: https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/tflite-python/ and saw I was missing:

1. Adding the load_delegate library

```
from tflite_runtime.interpreter import load_delegate
```

2. Calling the delegate

```
interpreter = Interpreter(model_path,
  experimental_delegates=[load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1.0')])
```

After these changes my model runs in the Coral board.